# CSS responsive nav bar remove content behind when opened haburger

Tags: html, css, responsive

This is my HTML and CSS

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.row {
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/* ------------ NAVIGATION ------------  */

.main-nav {
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.main-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.main-nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 90%;
}

.main-nav ul li a {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 15px;
}


.main-nav label #btn,
.main-nav label #cancel {
  font-size: 180%;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 40px;
  display: none;
}

.main-nav #check {
  display: none;
}

/* ------------ HEADER ------------  */

header {
  height: 100vh;
}

.landing {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1140px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.landing p {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 280%;
  font-weight: 300;
  word-spacing: 3px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}



/* ------------ BUTTONS ------------  */

.btn:link,
.btn:visited {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #0097e6;
  border-radius: 200px;
  color: #fff;
}

/* ------------ MEDIA QUERIES ------------  */
@media (max-width: 860px) {

  .main-nav label #btn {
    display: block;
  }
  .main-nav ul {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    top: 80px;
    left: -100%;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all .5s;
  }
  .main-nav ul li{
    display: block;
    margin: 50px 0;
    line-height: 30px;
  }
  .main-nav #check:checked ~ ul {
    left: 0;
  }
  .main-nav #check:checked ~ label #btn {
    display: none;
  }
  .main-nav #check:checked ~ label #cancel {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>


    <header>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="main-nav">
          <nav>
            <input type="checkbox" id="check">
            <label for="check">
              <i class="fas fa-bars" id="btn"></i>
              <i class="fas fa-times" id="cancel"></i>
            </label>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact me</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="landing">
        <h1>One</h1>
        <p>Two</p>
      </div>
    </header>

  </body>
</html>
```

**Details**

I have just finished creating a responsive navigation depending on the device width.

**Problem**

[image]

Here as you can see the navigation contents such as the `li` are showing along with the `header` content behind. Does not look good!

**Question**

What do I need to do - to blank out all content behind the navigation bar when I have opened the menu? So it shows the navigation bar only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there are a number of other aspects that should be improved, a simple solution for what I suspect you want would be to add these styles to your `ul`:

```
ul {
    position: relative; /* allows for z-index usage */
    z-index: 2; /* value higher than that of the content you want 'behind' */
    background-color: #fff; /* non-transparent background */
}
```

Comment: Hi Ryan - thanks for the answer. What aspects need improving?

Comment: Also - I have managed to achieve it by doing. `Position: fixed; z-index: 2;`

Comment: @LV98, I would start by looking into alternatives for your usage of `display: none;` to hide elements: [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/hide-elements-in-css/) is a good read. As well as using `float`.

Comment: @LV98, yes, `position: fixed;` also allows for setting the `z-index`. It's a matter of what exactly you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can ether use JavaScript to change the display to non of the div you want to hide or make the background-color of the responsive color white so that it hides what ever is behind it.